# Reward not solved question

Tags: discussion

I had a question, *[Connect two subnets on Linux](https://superuser.com/questions/1007200/connect-two-subnets-linux)*, which is not solved yet. But user TomS has done many constructive attempts to solve it. Which does give me a direction where to search further. I would like reward him for that. How can I do so, because the question is not solved?

Comment: You reward the user by voting his answer up, indicating that the answer was helpful, instead of of indicating it was unhelpful and voting it down.  If the answer does not solve the problem it should not be accepted.  If you accept the answer, that is an indication you solved your problem, because of the answer.

Comment: Thanks. I tried, but it requires a minimum of 15 points

Comment: You will have to wait until you have 15 reputation points in that case.

Comment: You'll get to 15 points with one upvoted question or answer, or accepted edits to improve two posts.

Comment: There, now you have the rep you need.

Comment: @Bernard Optionally once you have enough reputation, you can start a bounty and award him with it. (if you're feeling extra nice)

Comment: Essentially the point is that an answer can be helpful without *solving* the problem. An upvote just means you want to highlight that the answer has relevant value, it's not required that you only upvote 'correct' answers.